# Write words within a certain length

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

I am looking for a way to write some words within a certain length, filled by space on the right side, so that I could align words without making a table.

Image that there is a command to do so, let's say `\textlength{10cm}`, then we could do the following:

```
\begin{compactitem}
\item \textlength{10cm}{abcdefg} hijklmn 
\item \textlength{10cm}{opqrstuvw} xyz
\end{compactitem}
```

Then, we will see that `abcdefg` and `opqrstuvw` are left justified, followed by space, and `hijklmn` and `xyz` are left justified.

Does anyone know how to realise this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a regular

```
\newcommand{\textlength}[2][l]{\makebox[#2][#1]}
```

which sets the content in a fixed-width `\makebox` with a `l`eft-alignment. You can change this as well, to suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% \textlength[<halign>]{<width>}{<stuff>}
\newcommand{\textlength}[2][l]{\makebox[#2][#1]}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \textlength{7cm}{abcdefg} hijklmn 
  \item \textlength{7cm}{opqrstuvw} xyz
  \item \textlength[r]{7cm}{abcdef} hijklmn
  \item \textlength[c]{7cm}{opqrstuvw} xyz
  \item \textlength[s]{7cm}{a b c d e f g} hijklmn
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```